# Custom DialogFragment not working

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I want to use custom dialog in my Android app so I create a class that extends DialogFragment and I use it in a Fragment class however it's not working.

There is my custom dialog class:

```
public class MyDialogue extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {   
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_dialog, null);  
    }
}
//my_dialog.xml has the layout of dialog
```

enterData(View view) method is set onClick property of a button in espensecashfragment.xml
There is my fragment from which my dialog should be shown :

```
//This is where I want to use the dialog
public class ExpenseCashFragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expensecashfragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void enterData(View view){
          FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
          MyDialogue myDialogue = new MyDialogue();
          myDialogue.show(manager, "MyDialogue");
    }
}
```

There is part of espensecashfragment.xml, button linked to enterData method :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/enterButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Enter"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom ="100dp"
    android:onClick="enterData" />
```

Comment: From were are you calling enterData(View view)... add code

Comment: @user3473222 the method `enterdata(View)` must be within the Activity that hosts the `ExpenseCashFragment`. If you look at the [View source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.2_r1/android/view/View.java#2125), reflection is being used to get the method out of the context, which is the activity.

Comment: I made a public method in Activity that calls the ExpenseCashFragment.                                                 **public void dialogEC()** ...This method contains the three lines of code of enterData(View view).  Once I made this, the show() method rise an error;;